# Via sizing in Altium

Tags: pcb-design, power-electronics, high-current, via

[image]

I am making Vias on my PCB Design in Altium. I had query on how to relate the **reference plane opening diameter** and the **via plating thickness** on the Saturn PCB Calculator for my vias in the Altium design?

Answer (score 0):

**Opening diameter** is a combination of two settings:

1. Directly in the via settings you can set the size of the copper pad in the (potentially unconnected) middle layers (like a reference plane is).
2. Additionally there is the Design Rule Electrical->Clearance from Copper to Via.

These two parameters together make up the entire opening in unconnected middle layers.

**Via plating thickness** can not be configured in Altium Designer. This is something your Fab House will typically give you as a fixed parameter for a specific process. Most of the time they just refer to IPC-6012E (it specifies a minimum average thickness of 20 µm for IPC Class I and II, while IPC Class III holes require an average of at least 25 µm)

[image]
[image]
[image]